# Bootstrap 3 Datepicker in Angular 2+ with or without jquery

Tags: jquery, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am new to Angular 2+. I am trying to integrate Bootstrap 3 Datepicker in 
AngularJS2. I used the [solution]: [How to use Bootstrap 3 Datepicker in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37944715/how-to-use-bootstrap-3-datepicker-in-angular-2). But got error like

`Cannot find name '$'`

Is there any way to implement the task with or without jquery?

My code given below.

index.html

```
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script
 src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"
 integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30="
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">   </script>
```

new-job.component.html

```
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
   <input type='text' class="form-control" id='proposed_start_at' formControlName="proposed_start_at" #proposed_start_at/>
   <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="proposed_start_at">Start Time</label>
</div>
```

new-job.component.ts

```
@ViewChild("proposed_start_at")
public startDateElementRef: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    $(this.startDateElementRef.nativeElement).datetimepicker({format: 'LT'});
}
```

I want to implement datetimepicker which is given in [link]: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add: `declare var $:any;`

```
declare var $: any;

@Component({
    ...
})
```

Be sure to have all required librairies in your librairies:

```
npm install jquery bootstrap moment eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker--save
```

then in angular-cli.json

```
"styles": ["../node_modules/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css"],
"scripts": [
      "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
      "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
      "../node_modules/moment/moment.js",
      "../node_modules/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js",
      ...
```

And you dont need to add these in scripts tags in index.html

Comment: Thanks. Now error message gone. But in console I am getting `$ is not a function`

Comment: add the bootstrap-datepicker js & css in your script tag & style tag: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-datetimepicker , or by npm install & declaring in angular-cli.json

Comment: Current links and scripts tags are given below. 
  
 ` <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker-standalone.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>` But still getting `Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: $ is not a function`

Comment: Giving same error with `Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery`.

Comment: Could you recheck this answer? I think you need to add jquery & bootstrap & moment & bootstrap-datetimepicker from npm , then adding theses in angular-cli.json . And you can remove these in script tags